# TEXT formula does not work in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, date-time, validation

I try to find difference between two date and time value in SharePoint 2010. I have two common column (date and time) and I use this formula =TEXT(Column2-Column1,"h:mm:ss") but it does not work? I get error "Invalid formula"

Could someone help me?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the locale of you site?

Comment: Local is Polish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wrapping the column names in square brackets?

*=TEXT([Column2]-[Column1],"h:mm:ss")*

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Yes of course I did it but still I have the same error "The formula contains a syntrax error or is not supported" Can I reach my goal by other method?

Comment: There's a section in the article that says the delimiter may change from ',' to ';' depending on culture settings. It also says that the conversion should be automatic, but I would give it a try anyway. Have you tried testing it with DATEDIF?

Comment: I was also thinking to confirm if the input dates/columns are correct, but you mentioned that the formula itself is throwing the error.

Comment: I just tested it on a generic list with this formula, it works. It is also unable to accept the semi-colon as a delimiter in my case.

=TEXT([Modified]-[Created], "h:mm:ss")

,returns single line of text.

Comment: You are big! I missed culture settings and when I changed "," to ";" It started works but now I am wondering if is formula which shows difference but with time and date? not only time like in this?